# How to secure applications that are vulnerable to quotation character without changing code?

Tags: security, networking, sharepoint, sql-injection

I have discovered that in our network the security guys blocked GET requests that contain characters like <, >, ", ' and their encoded equivalents. These are character that are required by many web applications to function properly and even when building new apps we have to take this restrictive rule into account. We have to do different sort of hacks to make out-of-the-box or even new apps work. When I discussed the matter it turned out that they have many old apps at hand that have vulnerabilities that can be triggered by these characters (SQL Injection,...) and they don't have access to people to solve these issues so instead they have decided to block these request all together. Still I find it hard to believe if there is no other way around this.

I am wondering how other enterprises achieve the same without putting such a limitation in place or to be precise:
**How can we secure those old web application without changing their source code and blocking all requests even for new applications that do not have these vulnerabilities, in a cost effective way?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach taken by your network security team is not *completely* absurd, but it's being too broadly applied.

For example, IIS 7 (and up) can use the [URL Rewrite extension](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to apply specific request-blocking rules to **specific sites** (and even specific domains); it does **not** need to apply such rules to *all* network traffic. Third-party programs (such as ISAPI Rewrite) can be used by IIS 6 to similar effect.

A more sensible approach would be to set up restrictive request rules on all the sites that host the vulnerable legacy web applications, while allowing your modern web applications to receive unblocked requests as normal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should also mention that we are using different technologies here and IIS is not the only web application server. Is there a way to do the same at a lower level so to affect all requests and still target specific application?

Comment: For advice on how to set up request-blocking rules for non-IIS web servers (such as Apache using mod_rewrite), I recommend first checking to see if anyone has already asked such a question for your specific technology set on Stack Overflow, and if not, go ahead and ask as a separate question. I still believe targeted request blocking (on a per web application basis) is more appropriate to your scenario than a network-wide restriction on all GET requests.